# Why does my program only run if I console.log at the beginning?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to practice overriding/monkey-patching a method definition, so I wrote this:

```
const p = Array.prototype.push;

Array.prototype.push = function() {
  console.log("X");
  return p.apply(this, arguments);
};

const nums = [1, 2];
nums.push(3);
console.log(nums);
```

I ran it with Node 10.11.0 and nothing happened. I got zero output of any kind, and no errors.

If I add a single `console.log` call at the very beginning, and change absolutely nothing else, it suddenly works exactly as I expect.

```
console.log("Blah");
const p = Array.prototype.push;

Array.prototype.push = function() {
  console.log("X");
  return p.apply(this, arguments);
};

const nums = [1, 2];
nums.push(3);
console.log(nums);
```

This seems absolutely bizarre to me and I can't imagine any reason it would happen. Nor can I find any evidence of a similar problem on Google.

Comment: The only thing that printing should effect is other printing actions. The more likely explanation is something was off with how it was being run the first time, and it was fixed the second time it was run; and you happened to add a print at that time. FWIW, I just ran the first one on a console on my phone, and it ran fine.

Comment: The first code snippet it's printing the expected output to me.

Comment: It is working fine in browser and  now there are lot of logs :-)

Comment: its work for me on `node v8.11.1`

Comment: I can reproduce this; my guess is that console.log() output is put into a buffer before it is actually displayed, and since the process ends immediately after, the buffer is never fully dumped into the terminal. Adding more log commands changes this, but the node version also seems significant. I'm on 10.10.0